# Javascript set attribute using variable

Tags: javascript

I'm unsure of the syntax here, but the code I have so far is this... (Note: I am passing the id's of three textboxes in the form '#begmile','#endmile','#totmile', and I want to set the value of the 'totmile' checkbox to endmile-bigmile)

```
function subtract(begmile, endmile, totmile){
y=$(begmile).attr('value');
z=$(endmile).attr('value');
y=z-y;
$(totmile).setAttr('value',???);
```

}

I'm not sure if my syntax here so far is correct, but assuming it is (that y is properly set to endmile-begmile, how do I use setAttr to set the value of totmile to the value of y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
var href = 'http://cnn.com';

$(selector).attr('href', href);
```

Comment: Thanks, figured this would be an easy question. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

your last line isn't calling the right method:

```
$(totmile).setAttr('value',???);
```

should be:

```
$(totmile).attr('value',???);
```

e.g.

```
$(totmile).attr('value', y);//set the value to the variable "y"
```

you can also call `.val();` instead to easily get the value of a field, or `.val(newValue);` to set the value.

also note that if your values for "y" and "z" are not actually representing numbers you'll get a weird result.

Comment: Thank you. Just for reference then, when should setAttr be used?

Comment: The full `.setAttribute(name, value);` is a DOM method (not jQuery) that can set any attribute on any element. (well, not exactly any... as there are a bunch of IE bugs, but in theory any attribute ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The `value` attribute refers to the default value for the textbox, not the current one. The current one is stored in the `value` *property*.

```
function subtract(begmile, endmile, totmile) {
    document.getElementById(totmile).value =
      document.getElementById(endmile).value - document.getElementById(begmile).value;
}
```

This also removes the need for jQuery, since the JavaScript Sledgehammer is far too excessive for this job. To make sure it works, just remove the `#` when you pass IDs to the function.